# Is there a way to require loopback4 as a node module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, require, loopback4

I've been working for a long time with Loopback3, but it has reached EOL, so now I'm starting to migrate to LB4, the thing is, I've been digging around and haven't found a specific way to require LB4 as a node module, as it is possible with LB3 (https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Working-with-LoopBack-objects.html). I'm pretty sure I should be importing LB4 from the dist built folder, but I haven't even found any reference or example on how to use it, if it is even possible.

Comment: Would it be `import {get} from '@loopback/rest'` or similar? See https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Getting-started.html.